# Convert C++ string variable to long

Tags: c++, string, long-integer

I have a variable:

```
string item;
```

It gets initialized at run-time. I need to convert it to long. How to do it? I have tried atol() and strtol() but I always get following error for strtol() and atol() respectively:

```
cannot convert 'std::string' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'long int strtol(const char*, char**, int)'

cannot convert 'std::string' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'long int atol(const char*)'
```

Comment: string has a function c_str that will expose it as a const char*

Comment: `item.c_str()` will return `const char*` of the `std::string`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try like this:

```
long i = atol(item.c_str());
```

Comment: thnx! I was not knowing that C++ string needs to be converted to char* using c_str()

Comment: -1 for `long i = atol(item.c_str());` because this function is unsafe!

Comment: @tenfour: Trying this : `cout << atoi("9879abc879xyz"); ` See what it prints!

Comment: I guess we have different ideas what it means for something to be "unsafe". This is just quirky behavior which in a lot of situations is even preferred. Obviously `atol` is about 3-4 levels away from being a great answer, but "unsafe" seems like an exaggeration.

Comment: @tenfour: It is unsafe, because it doesn't tell you that it didn't *really* convert the *whole* string, and doesn't tell you the problem. It is unsafe because it doesn't tell you the between these two calls : `atoi("0")` and `atoi("abc")`. [Both return `0`](http://ideone.com/z62qj). :P

Comment: @Nawaz: In my case, its confirm that string s containing only digits would be passed. Well what do you recommend?

Comment: -1 becase for 1 this is unsafe, for 2 it's C function so you should not use it unless you have explicitly C string. there are C++ functions for this so use them. Next one should be marked as correct not this one.

Comment: It would be helpful instead of saying that it is unsafe, to provide a safer version. Because now, I need to find a safer answer.

Answer (score 23):

c++11:

```
long l = std::stol(item);
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

C++98:

```
char * pEnd;.
long l = std::strtol(item.c_str(),&pEnd,10);
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol

Comment: Worth mentioning this is `C++11`, so you'll need to check you have an up to date compiler, and which flags to use.

Comment: -1 for `long l = atol(item.c_str());` because this function is unsafe!

Comment: @Nawaz: "Unsafe" is a bit hyperbolic. It doesn't allow you to check whether the input really was a numerical string; whether or not that's "safe" depends on where it comes from and what you're doing with it.

Comment: For the record calls to `atol` result in undefined behavior if an error occurred.

Comment: @Nawaz this is why I check to make sure my string is a valid number before I do anything like these top to examples. But is it still "Unsafe" if I do  this?

Answer (score 6):

Use a string stream.

```
#include <sstream>

// code...
std::string text;
std::stringstream buffer(text);
long var;
buffer >> var;
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [std::stol](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) < characters to fill space >

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have access to C++11, and you can use the boost library, you can consider this option:

```
long l = boost::lexical_cast< long >( item );
```