# How to convert a char to int in Arduino

Tags: c++, char, arduino, int, type-conversion

I receive some data in a char variable, and the result in teststring is always a number. How can I convert this number to a variable int?

After that I can put the int variable on delay time. There is a piece of my code:

```
String readString = String(30);
String teststring = String(100);
int convertedstring;

teststring = readString.substring(14, 18); (Result is 1000)

digitalWrite(start_pin, HIGH);
delay(convertedstring); // Result of teststring convert
digitalWrite(start_pin, LOW);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:

```
long number = atol(input); // Notice the function change to atoL
```

Or, if you want to use only positive values:

Code:

```
unsigned long number = strtoul(input, NULL, 10);
```

Reference: http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/atol.3.asp

Or,

```
int convertedstring = atoi(teststring.c_str());
```

Comment: Error: cannot convert 'String' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int atoi(const char*)'

Comment: That's my try: 
long number = atol( teststring );

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776210/convert-c-string-variable-to-long it can help you

Comment: also this link is usefull : http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,103511.0.html

Comment: It-s working! int convertedstring = atoi(teststring.c_str()); Tnk you

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the atoi function in your Arduino environment?

If not, you can just write some simple conversion code in there:

```
int my_atoi(const char *s)
{
    int sign=1;
    if (*s == '-')
        sign = -1;
    s++;
    int num = 0;
    while(*s)
    {
        num = ((*s)-'0') + num*10;
        s++;
    }
    return num*sign;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you might have a bug where the pointer `s` is always incremented even when the first character is not '-'?

Answer (score 0):

String to Long Arduino IDE:

```
    //stringToLong.h

    long stringToLong(String value) {
    long outLong=0;
        long inLong=1;
        int c = 0;
        int idx=value.length()-1;
        for(int i=0;i<=idx;i++){

            c=(int)value[idx-i];
            outLong+=inLong*(c-48);
            inLong*=10;
        }
        return outLong;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"String to Long Arduino IDE"*?